# Javascript: How do I force a new tab to open after a quiz (in prompt) was solved wrong?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm curious about how do I force js to open a new tab if the quiz is solved wrong? The idea is to open a new tab with some information about the quiz so that the person could solve it correctly next time.

First I tried using **if** and then I tried using **while**, but it doesn't work either:

```
 while(score < 3){
    function myFunction(){
        window.open("theory.html", '_blank');
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You definitely want to use an `if` statement, but you probably want to do that *inside* the function. Something like: `function myFunction() { if (score < 3) {window.open(..., '_blank');}`

Comment: Hi Max, I don't think you can nowadays mate. Most browsers block this functionality due to its abuse. You will have to use an internal popup or overlay of some sort that doesn't result in a new window or tab being opened via the browser.

Comment: @DCdaz has a good point, many browsers will block this with their popup blockers.

Comment: @SumnerEvans I think Chrome just ignores these types of requests fully now. That'll go for IE Edge I'd assume too.

Comment: I would look into a javascript modal library, there are tons available. A modal is basically an "in window popup" that pops over the content, but isn't actually a new window/tab.

Comment: If they're doing a quiz then they might be clicking a submit button at the end? you could tie the window opening to that. it would count as "user triggered" for the purposes of most popup blockers.